# Removing a callback C#

Tags: c#, callback

I have a method where I am accepting a callback as a parameter.

```
public void SaveSomeData (int value, Action<SomeDataModel> callback)
```

This is a method on client where I aggregate all the calls made for specific amount of time and then send a single request to the server. Once server sends the response, I notify the callers using callback. This all works fine.

However, a problem I am trying to solve is when a call is made to this method from the same place, I only want to notify the caller once and ignore(discard) any other callbacks.

One way I can do this is to just ignore the duplicate callback (by looking at `callback.Method.Name`) but then the question is if the duplicate callbacks continue to stay in memory?

Looking for a better way to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: This question isn't bad, but including a bit more information could help. Could you post the code that currently solves the problem as well?

Comment: The better solution is to avoid scheduling multiple callbacks when you only want to be notified once, rather than trying to have the object only invoke unique callback methods.  After all, this method has no way of knowing if a particular caller *wants* to be notified multiple times, and it's not its job to know.